# eliminating manual chr(13)|| entries for 2 or 3, to infinite lines of text

Tags: sql-server

Good morning, All.
I have an ugly lump of code that I need to simplify. And since I am in Data Services Designer, SQL Server 2008, I can’t use T-SQL.

The issue is that I need to take huge globs of text notes, cut them down to varchar(100) chunks, turn those into an organized block of text, and be able to not add all of the extra chr(13) carriage returns when there is only 3 lines of text, not 59 or more. Or be able to add extra chr(13)|| RP_ROW_to_COL.”*_TEXT_NOTE” where there are hundreds of lines of text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
RP_ROW_to_COL.USER_ID||
chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL.SETUP_DT||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."1_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."2_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."3_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."4_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."5_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."6_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."7_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."8_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."9_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."10_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."11_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."12_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."13_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."14_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."15_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."16_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."17_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."18_TEXT_NOTE"||chr(13)||RP_ROW_to_COL."19_TEXT_NOTE”
```

Comment: Can you please add sample input and expected output

Comment: If you can't use TSQL, then why did you tag it?

Comment: hmm... the sample didn't format well enough to demonstrate the issue.. I will see if I can figure out a better way.

Comment: I didn't tag t-sql, a moderator edited my post.

Comment: replace_substr(<table_name>.<column_name>, chr(13), null)